# How do I apply 3D transform on iframe child elements?

Tags: jquery, ios, css, html, cordova

Using the technique described here on a Phonegap 2.0.0 iOS 6.0.1 app:

http://cantina.co/2012/03/06/ios-5-native-scrolling-grins-and-gothcas/

I have tried various variations of:

```
iframe * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

It does not seem I can apply hardware acceleration to the child elements in an iframe, which is in fact scrolling, but in a jerky non-smooth fashion.

How might I achieve smoother scrolling of the iframe content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this, if the iframe shows an external website page.

And also you cannot define a css rule for an iframe content like that. It's impossible.

But there is an alternative method with `jQuery`,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("*").css("-webkit-transform","translate3d(0,0,0)");
});​
```

*but don't forget, this works just on same domain.

Comment: Only in the same domain, even on the iPhone via phonegap which isn't subject to the same origin policy?